# how to download logs file using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

```
> In Xcode, go to Window -> Devices.
> Select your device in the left panel.
> Click the little arrow as shown in the screenshot below.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/acpO7.png

[image]

How to get above image contain refer above url and step.

my question of how to fetch above image display all contain and write file.
means my device which application open and how many time open data fetch.

for example of me create this type application:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerodesktop.appdetox.qualitytime&hl=en

Comment: Your question is not clear. 1. Still from the image link, Select your iPhone in the organizer, click Device Logs. You would see all NSLog outputs in the log. 2. Select your project in same window and then you can "view device logs". There you can download entire logs and data. 3. Crash logs are also present in the device, and you can go to it via settings. Navigate to Settings - Privacy - Diagnostics & usage - Diagnostics & usage Data.; this will have crash logs.

Comment: my simple question of my device log print my app.

Comment: you want to see nslogs from your app ?

Comment: yes, log file contain print in console.

Comment: Thats what I suggested in 1st option above. Select your iPhone in the organizer, click Device Logs. You would see all NSLog outputs in the log.

Comment: it is possible but this data get in my application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115372/discussion-between-bhadresh-kathiriya-and-user3300864).

Comment: get in my application..what do you mean by this ? you want these console logs to be displayed inside your app. Then add a textField or an alert view; to show the same logs on UI.